# the correct command of install tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

When trying to install Tensorflow on Anaconda, I tried two types of commands. `conda install tensorflow-gpu` works just fine. However, when trying `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu` as shown [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu). It gives the following error message.

```
Fetching package metadata ...
CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/linux-64/repodata.json>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /anaconda/linux-64/repodata.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x2b8e3f4ec110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))",),)
```

What can the be reason?

Comment: Did you try installing again

Comment: Your internet connections seem to be the problem, try increasing https timeout!

Comment: You should avoid installing the anaconda version and instead use pip if possible. The conda version is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some who might not know the `-c` or `--channel` option adds a `channel` for `conda` to search for the package.

Please try the follwoing:

```
anaconda logout
conda update conda
```

than try to re-install

also please look at the official [web-site](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingAnaconda) to see specifics of installing `TensorFlow` using `Anaconda` installation

Answer (score 2):

There is two type of tensor-flow :

1. TensorFlow with CPU support only
2. TensorFlow with GPU support

You must pick the mechanism by which you install TensorFlow. The supported choices are as follows:

1. [virtualenv](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingVirtualenv)
2. [using pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingNativePip)
3. [Docker](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingDocker)
4. [Anaconda](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingAnaconda)

I give step by using pip

To **install** run following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev   # for Python 2.7
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev # for Python 3.n

pip install tensorflow     # Python 2.7; for CPU support
pip3 install tensorflow    # Python 3.n; for CPU support
pip install tensorflow-gpu # Python 2.7;  for GPU support
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu # Python 3.n; for GPU support
```

To **uninstall** run following command in terminal  :

```
sudo pip uninstall tensorflow  # for Python 2.7
sudo pip3 uninstall tensorflow # for Python 3.n
```