# Error while doing "import tensorflow" (Tensorflow installation error Windows 10)

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

Error while doing "import tensorflow" (Tensorflow installation error Windows 10):
Installed successfully by typing **pip3 install tensorflow** at command prompt. (I have both Python 2.7.11 and Python 3.5.2 installed, but i'm installing tensorflow for Python 3 (using *pip3*)). It is a CPU installation, not a GPU one. When I try to do "import tensorflow", it gives the following error.I have checked the DLL files as well. C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSVCP140.DLL file is present. Please help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
            return importlib.import_module(mname)
    File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
            from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
    File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
            _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
    File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
            return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
    File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
            import tensorflow
    File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
            from tensorflow.python import *
    File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
            from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
    File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
            raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
            return importlib.import_module(mname)
    File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

The traceback goes on like that goes on like that...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the correct command of install tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428427/the-correct-command-of-install-tensorflow)

Comment: I see you are trying to install on Windows, @mrry has a great installation troubleshooter script that can help pinpoint issues available here: [mrry's Self-check Script](https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c) Can you also please confirm if you are installing the CPU version or the GPU version?

Comment: I am installing the CPU version, using the command pip3 install tensorflow for Python 3.5.2 IDLE. In the Command prompt, it said, "Successfully installed tensorflow". But when I try to do "import tensorflow" in the IDLE, it gives this long list of errors...

Comment: It's fixed now!

I had to download and install the Visual C++ 2015 redistributable (x64 version) file then restart my machine..

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed now!

I had to download and install the Visual C++ 2015 redistributable (x64 version) file from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587) and then restart my machine.