# "import tensorflow" error on windows with python 3.6.2 CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just wanted to try out tensorflow but whenever I try to execute the following, I get an error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

The error message is:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I already searched for a solution in the following threads:

[Error while doing "import tensorflow" (Tensorflow installation error Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461927/error-while-doing-import-tensorflow-tensorflow-installation-error-windows-10)

[On Windows, running "import tensorflow" generates No module named "_pywrap_tensorflow" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso)

Everytime the suggested solution was to install "Visual C++ 2015 redistributable (x64 version)" to get the "MSVCP140.DLL". I installed [update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587), but it didn't help. I can anyway find the dll with the "where" command:

```
C:\>where msvcp140.dll
C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll
```

My PC is running on Windows 10. The installed python version is 3.6.2

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an easy solution. Althoug the setup worked on another computer, here I needed to install an older version of tensorflow.

```
pip install tensorflow==1.5
```

Thanks to the hints in the comments for the [self check script](https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c).

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks! Acctually I removed the 1.7 version first using the command ``pip uninstall tensorflow``

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which version of tf you installed, if you haven't obtained it from the uci repository for 64 bit Windows binaries, try removing the version you have (pip uninstall tensorflow) and then download and pip installing the version from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow). Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you please clarify, why it should help to use these "unofficial" binaries?

Comment: Tf and a number of it's dependencies require compilation of C, Fortran and Cython code prior to use. The packages from the "unofficial" binaries website are pre-compiled and are widely utilized by the Python community developing on windows.

Comment: I downloaded and installed: `pip install tensorflow-1.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` Unfortunately I still get the same error message when importing tensorflow.

Comment: I just noticed the error is shorter. Now it's only 2 errors with "DLL load failed". Here is the beginning: `File "C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows) and install tensorflow in anaconda. if your already using anaconda then install tesnorflow using `conda install tensorflow`

Comment: Can you please clarify why it should help to use Anaconda? I'd like to stay with the officially supported way as long as possible.

Comment: it is not an unofficial way. anaconda is python distribution. the packages version managed by `conda` you can create many virtual  environment each environment you can install python packages. [refer](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)